# Count missing cell in panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data frame similar to this :

| Item | Company | Branch | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | 1 | 5 |
| Second | B | 2 | 8 |

I want to count the number or the rows where one or more of the columns value is blank or N/A  (using *or* function between columns)

| Item | Company | Branch | Price | Uncompleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | 1 | 5. | True |
| Second | B | 2 | 8. | Flase |
| Third. |  | N/A. | 9. | True |

So the result should appear like that:  the number of rows with missing value is 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of rows having one or more missing values:

```
# df is your data frame
df.shape[0] - df.dropna().shape[0]
```